# first flask app installed on multi-app apache deployment works but not the second

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi

I have been having problems deploying flask apps to my remote server for the first time. I often go through some long, involved, doing whatever I can steps and eventually the app starts working. But this cannot go on.

So, here I have my conf file. I can add one app and the app works. Then I add the second app and the first one still works but the second one is returning a 404.

One problem is that I am not seeing where to see errors anywhere. I see a 404 in the access.log and nothing for that request in the error.log. Where might WSGI-specific errors be seen?

The first app works. You can see it at https://opencalaccess.org/cdcr/ and https://opencalaccess.org/test_wsgi works.

I know (or are pretty sure) that the flask application itself is ok. I can run:

```
$ ./.venv/bin/python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
  * Serving Flask app 'data_brokers'
  * Debug mode: on
 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
  * Running on http://50.116.13.181:8080
 Press CTRL+C to quit
  * Restarting with stat
  * Debugger is active!
  * Debugger PIN: 526-161-898
 71.202.194.221 - - [28/Mar/2024 09:17:47] "GET /data_brokers/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So this works ok. I can get data and everything else, but:

```
 # cat opencalaccess.org-le-ssl.conf
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
 <VirtualHost *:443>
 
    ServerName opencalaccess.org
 
    ServerAlias www.opencalaccess.org
 
    ServerAdmin ray@ganymede.org
 
    RewriteEngine On
 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/opencalaccess_org
 
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info
 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opencalaccess_org_ssl/access.log combined
 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/opencalaccess_org_ssl/error.log
 
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 
    # example, shows that WSGI is installed, working.
    WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi /var/www/opencalaccess_org/test_script.py
 
    WSGIDaemonProcess cdcr threads=2 user=ray python-home=/home/ray/cdcr_www/.venv home=/home/ray/cdcr_www/
    WSGIScriptAlias /cdcr /home/ray/cdcr_www/cdcr.py
    <Directory /home/ray/cdcr_www/>
        WSGIProcessGroup cdcr
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
    WSGIDaemonProcess data_brokers threads=2 user=ray python-home=/home/ray/data_brokers/.venv home=/home/ray/data_brokers
    WSGIScriptAlias /data_brokers /home/ray/data_brokers/data_brokers.py
    <Directory /home/ray/data_brokers/>
        WSGIProcessGroup data_brokers
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
 
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
 
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/opencalaccess.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/opencalaccess.com/privkey.pem
 </VirtualHost>
 </IfModule>
```

But I see:

```
 $ curl -I 'https://opencalaccess.org/cdcr/'
 HTTP/2 200
 date: Thu, 28 Mar 2024 17:34:02 GMT
 content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 vary: Accept-Encoding
 
 $ curl -I 'https://opencalaccess.org/data_brokers/'
 HTTP/2 404
 date: Thu, 28 Mar 2024 17:34:11 GMT
 content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And here I can check all of the directories and files referred to in the apps' definitions:

```
 # ls -ld /home/ray/cdcr_www/.venv
 drwxrwxr-x 5 ray ray 4096 Aug 26  2023 /home/ray/cdcr_www/.venv
 # 
 # ls -ld /home/ray/data_brokers/.venv
 drwxrwxr-x 5 ray ray 4096 Mar 27 19:55 /home/ray/data_brokers/.venv
 # 
 # ls -ld /home/ray/cdcr_www/
 drwxrwxr-x 6 ray ray 4096 Feb  7 17:29 /home/ray/cdcr_www/
 # 
 # ls -ld /home/ray/data_brokers/
 drwxrwxr-x 5 ray ray 4096 Mar 27 19:55 /home/ray/data_brokers/
 # 
 # ls -l /home/ray/cdcr_www/cdcr.py
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 1745 Feb  7 17:29 /home/ray/cdcr_www/cdcr.py
 # 
 # ls -l /home/ray/data_brokers/data_brokers.py
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 801 Mar 28 09:27 /home/ray/data_brokers/data_brokers.py
 # 
 # ls -ld /home/ray/cdcr_www/
 drwxrwxr-x 6 ray ray 4096 Feb  7 17:29 /home/ray/cdcr_www/
 # 
 # ls -ld /home/ray/data_brokers/
 drwxrwxr-x 5 ray ray 4096 Mar 27 19:55 /home/ray/data_brokers/
 #
```

The definitions for the apps in the config file look pretty similar to me.

How can I see what else is wrong?